# UPDATE FROM with JOIN over ctid leads to Seq Scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-11

To clarify my problem I have created a test table with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_large (
    id int4 NOT NULL, -- Primary Key
    grp int4 NULL, -- Group ID
    descr text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_test_large PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_tl_grp ON public.test_large USING btree (grp);
```

The values in the column grp are assigned so that there are a maximum of 1000 records with the same value each.
In total there are 1.000.000 records.

The following update statement is a simplified version of a real statement:

```
update
    test_large d
set
    descr = s.descr
from
    (
    select
        ctid,
        *
    from
        test_large
    where
        grp = 1) s
where
    s.ctid = d.ctid;
```

The execution plan is:

```
Update on test_large d  (cost=139792.82..144832.96 rows=1000 width=53)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=139792.82..144832.96 rows=1000 width=53)
        Merge Cond: (d.ctid = test_large.ctid)
        ->  Sort  (cost=136816.68..139329.25 rows=1005029 width=14)
              Sort Key: d.ctid
              ->  Seq Scan on test_large d  (cost=0.00..19443.29 rows=1005029 width=14)
        ->  Sort  (cost=2976.14..2978.64 rows=1000 width=39)
              Sort Key: test_large.ctid
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_large  (cost=20.18..2926.31 rows=1000 width=39)
                    Recheck Cond: (grp = 1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_tl_grp  (cost=0.00..19.93 rows=1000 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (grp = 1)
```

As you can see, a Seq Scan of all 1,000,000 lines is performed for the update, in order to then execute a merge join instead of accessing the line directly via the CTID.

Is there any way to affect that? I could of course use the primary key in the WHERE condition, but then an additional index access would be required.

Comment: CTID comparison is typically slower than the PK comparison. Try `where s.id = d.id and s.grp = 1` to join on the primary key and also give the planner a hint that not all rows in the table will be updated (essentially repeating the inner WHERE clause that limits the number of rows returned)

Comment: I known using the primary key will make Postgres using an Index Scan. But I thought that with an index access, the index has to be read first in order to read the actual data block, while an access via the CTID directly identifies the data block.

Comment: So did you verify that using the PK makes this slower or are you only assuming that?

Comment: I assumed that access via CTID would be faster, but I can't get the server to do such access at all, so I can't test if it's faster. Hence the question of how I can 'convince' Postgres to access via the CTID.